# final coalgebra of the ${_{<κ}}$(A×X) endo-functor in $Set^*$?

Tags: category-theory, game-theory, coalgebras

In the paper [Coalgebraic Games and Strategies](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.261.3946&rep=rep1&type=pdf) F. Honsell, M. Lenisa, and R. Redamalla  use the functor $F_A$(X) = ${\mathscr{P}_{<κ}}$(A×X) to define games coalgebraically. This is a functor from the category of $Set^* \to Set^*$ where $Set^*$ is the category of sets satisfying the antifoundation axioms.

They state that the final $F_A$ coalgebra is ($G_A$,id) and that a game is to be understood as an element of $G_A$, but I don't know where the final coalgebra construction for $F_A$ is explained in detail. Why would id be the coalgebraic function?

They write

> The elements of the final coalgebra $G_A$ are the minimal graphs
>   up-to bisimilarity.

To add a bit more context as to how this relates to games:

> We consider a general notion of 2-player game of perfect information,
>   where the two players are called Left (L) and Right (R). A game x is
>   identified with its initial position; at any position, there are moves
>   for L and R, taking to new positions of the game. By abstracting from
>   superficial features of positions, games can be viewed as elements of
>   the final coalgebra for the functor F$_A$(X) = $\mathscr{P}_{<κ}$(A×X), where A is a
>   parametric set of atoms which encode information on moves and
>   positions, i.e. move names, and the player who has moved, and $\mathscr{P}_{<κ}$ is
>   the set of all subsets of cardinality < κ. The coalgebra structure
>   captures, for any position, the moves of the players and the
>   corresponding next positions.

as for the meaning of $\mathscr{P}_{<κ}$ this is explained in a later article ["Multigames and strategies, coalgebraically"](https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0304397515006416)

> $\mathscr{P}_{<κ}$is the set of all subsets of cardinality < κ, where κ can be ω, if only finitely branching games are considered, or it can be an inaccessible cardinal, if we are interested in more general games.

PS I posted this question [on mathoverflow yesterday](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320095/final-coalgebra-of-the-%CE%BAa%C3%97x-endo-functor-in-set), thinking I was on math.stackexchange...